# How to do both type of drag and drop for NSOutlineView?

Tags: swift, cocoa, drag-and-drop, appkit, nsoutlineview

How can I do Finder drag and drop style?

[image]

My ViewController code is something like this.

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        outlineView.registerForDraggedTypes([.string])
        outlineView.setDraggingSourceOperationMask(.move, forLocal: true)
    }
}
```

And the code for the drag and drop looks something like this.

```
extension ViewController: NSOutlineViewDataSource {
    func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, pasteboardWriterForItem item: Any) -> NSPasteboardWriting? {
        guard item is SidebarRow else { return nil }
        let sidebarRowIndex = outlineView.row(forItem: item) + -1
        
        return sidebarSections[0].rows[sidebarRowIndex].name.rawValue as NSString
    }
    
    func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, validateDrop info: NSDraggingInfo, proposedItem item: Any?, proposedChildIndex index: Int) -> NSDragOperation {
        guard let outlineView = info.draggingSource as? NSOutlineView else { return [] }
        outlineView.draggingDestinationFeedbackStyle = .gap
        return .move
    }
    
    func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, acceptDrop info: NSDraggingInfo, item: Any?, childIndex index: Int) -> Bool {
        guard item != nil else { return false }
        
        guard let items = info.draggingPasteboard.pasteboardItems,
              let pasteboardItem = items.first,
              let pasteboardItemName = pasteboardItem.string(forType: .string),
              let rowIndex = sidebarSections[0].rows.firstIndex(where: { $0.name.rawValue == pasteboardItemName }) else { return false }
        
        let new = sidebarSections[0].rows[rowIndex]
        
        sidebarSections[0].rows.remove(at: rowIndex)
        sidebarSections[0].rows.insert(new, at: index)

        outlineView.moveItem(at: rowIndex, inParent: item, to: index, inParent: item)

        return true
    }
}
```

My code doesn't quite do it.

Likewise, how do you do the other style of drag and drop?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried setting `draggingDestinationFeedbackStyle` earlier? `outlineView(_:draggingSession:endedAt:operation:)` is called when the dragginsession has ended = when the mouse button is released.

Comment: I edited my question. I pasted the wrong method. It was supposed to be `outlineView(_acceptDrop:childIndex:)`. The outcome is still the same.

Comment: `acceptDrop` is also called when the mouse button is released. The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstableview/draggingdestinationfeedbackstyle/gap) of `.gap` says to set the style in `outlineView(_:draggingSession:willBeginAt:forItems:)` but `viewDidLoad` is also an option. The `.gap` style looks a bit buggy to me.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40476374/10711707). My data models were structs. I have converted the sidebar row into class whilst retaining sidebar groups as structs.